# EOA delegating call authority to a contract to interact with another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, delegatecall, defi

Actually, I want my contract (say A) to interact with a project's contract (say B).

But, contract B's author has restricted calls by any contract. So with this, only one option is left i.e. an EOA calls Contract B directly. I was wondering if the following is possible:

> An EOA delegates 'calling authority' to a Contract account (referred to A) to make a call to another Contract account (referred to B).

Comment: How do they restrict the non-EOA calls in their contract?

Comment: By restricting the contract address types. Refer this code: https://github.com/abhi3700/evm_stablecoin_ds/blob/main/contracts/dependencies/CheckContract.sol#L11

Comment: If you're using the `extcodesize` trick then calling the contract's B functions from contract's A constructor is going to bypass this check. Maybe this is sufficient for you?

Comment: Actually, in here I want the user to connect with our SC-A & then get the activity done by calling SC-B. Moreover, I want to bypass the check in multiple call, not just in constructor only.

Comment: Read the docs for delegate.cash this protocol may have the solutions you're looking for. Also, Gains Network "1CT" Wallet used a similar workflow, but is not open source